# A closure of a set is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose the topological space $\left(X,\mathcal{T}_{X}\right)$ is given by $X= \left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{X}=\left\{ \left\{ 1,2\right\} ,\left\{ 2,3\right\} ,Ø,X;\left\{ 1,2,3\right\} ,\left\{ 2\right\} \right\}$.

Let $S = \left\{ 1,2\right\}$, then the set of limit points of $S$ is $S' = \left\{ 1,3\right\}$, the closure of $S$ should be $\textrm{cl}(S)=S\cup S'=\left\{ 1,2,3\right\}$.

The closure set $\textrm{cl}(S)=\left\{ 1,2,3\right\}$ should be a closed set by the property of closure, so its complement $X - \textrm{cl}(S) =\left\{ 4,5\right\}$ should be an open set. However, obviously, $\{ 4,5 \}\notin\mathcal{T}_{X}$, it is not an open set by the definition of $\mathcal{T}_{X}$.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. We say a point $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ meets $A\setminus\{x\}$. So according to this definition $S^\prime=\{1,3,4,5\}$. This implies $X-cl(S)=\{2\}$, which is open set.

Comment: This (thrice upvoted) answer is wrong: $2\in S\subset\operatorname{cl}(S).$

Comment: This is wrong: since $S=\{1,2\}$, we have $\textrm{cl}(S)=S\cup S'=\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} = X $ and  $X - \textrm{cl}(S)= Ø $

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to look separately at limit points.

$\operatorname{cl}(S)$ is defined as the smallest closed subset of $X$ containing $S.$

Since $S=\left\{1,2\right\}$ and the closed subsets are
$$\left\{3,4,5\right\} ,\left\{1,4,5\right\} ,X,\varnothing,\left\{4,5\right\} ,\left\{1,3,4,5\right\},$$

we obtain directly:

$$\operatorname{cl}(S)=X.$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in the comments, which are deleted by some other guys. I list it here.

---

In my main post, the error is that "$4,5$" are also limit points. This is because they are ***only*** contained in $X$, thus $X$ are the only open neighborhood of "$4$" and "$5$". They satisfy the definition of limit point of $S=\{1,2\}$ that: "A point $x \in X$ is a limit point of the set
$S$ if every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of
$S$ different from $x$ itself."

We then get $S'=\{1,3,4,5\}$, and $\textrm{cl}(S)=S\cup S'=\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} = X $.

We may also get $X - \textrm{cl}(S)= Ø $, which of course is an open set.